# Conditions to get a guard dog

Tags: halal-haram, dogs, pets

Aoa,I know that we as Muslims can not keep dogs as pets but majority scholars agree that guard dogs are permitted if kept outside the house.My question is that what are the conditions to get a guard dog. Even though my neighbourhood is relatively safe my mother and sister remain home alone for some part of the day so I was considering one. Kindly clarify. JazakAllah

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with keeping a guard dog if it has a real benefit and application, an example of which can be found in the Qur'an that the dog of the cave companions went to the cave like them and rested at the entrance of the cave.
But note that the religion of Islam has considered all dogs impure for any reason, and keeping the house and clothes clean, on which the correctness of prayer depends, will be difficult by keeping the dog. The guard dog must live outside the house and in its own place and not inside the house.

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa2443

https://www.pasokhkadeh.ir/15527/%D8%AD%DA%A9%D9%85-%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%87%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%B3%DA%AF-%D9%86%DA%AF%D9%87%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86/